# make picocli parse local date format

Tags: java, localdate, picocli

PicoCLI accepts `2019-04-26` as input for a `LocalDate` variable, but it does not accept the German Date format like `26.04.2019`.
For that you need:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy",Locale.GERMANY);
```

How do you tell to PicoCLI to use this formatter and not depend on US date input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a custom [type converter](https://picocli.info/#_custom_type_converters), either for a specific option, or globally for all options and positional parameters of a certain type.

Often the most compact way to register a custom converter is with a lambda expression:

```java
new CommandLine(new DateFormatDemo())
      .registerConverter(Date.class,
                         s -> new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMANY).parse(s))
      .execute(args);
```

If you need to set a converter **for a specific option**, you will need to define a class and specify that class in the `@Option(converter = X.class)` annotation of that option.

Note that it is okay to throw an exception from the `ITypeConverter.convert` method if the user input was invalid. Picocli will catch this exception and display an error message to the end user.

For example:

```java
class StrictGermanDateConverter implements ITypeConverter<Date> {
    @Override
    public Date convert(String value) throws Exception {
        Date result = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMANY).parse(value);
        if (result.getYear() < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("year should be after 1900");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is an example that uses this stricter converter to demonstrate:

- error checking
- registering a global type converter for all `java.util.Date` options
- invalid input results in picocli showing an error message followed by the usage help message

```java
import picocli.CommandLine;
import picocli.CommandLine.Command;
import picocli.CommandLine.ITypeConverter;
import picocli.CommandLine.Model.CommandSpec;
import picocli.CommandLine.Option;
import picocli.CommandLine.Spec;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

@Command(name = "demo")
public class DateFormatDemo implements Runnable {

    @Option(names = {"-d", "--date"}, description = "Date in German format `dd.MM.yyyy`",
            converter = StrictGermanDateConverter.class, paramLabel = "dd.MM.yyyy")
    Date specialDate;

    @Option(names = {"-x", "--default"}, paramLabel = "yyyy-MM-dd",
            description = "This option uses the default converter")
    Date defaultDate;

    @Spec CommandSpec spec;

    public void run() {
        List<String> args = spec.commandLine().getParseResult().originalArgs();
        System.out.printf("%s -> %s; %s%n", args, specialDate, defaultDate);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // invalid input: shows error message and usage help
        new CommandLine(new DateFormatDemo()).execute("-d=55.55.55");

        // alternatively, register a global converter
        // for _all_ Date options
        new CommandLine(new DateFormatDemo())
              .registerConverter(Date.class,
                   s -> new SimpleDateFormat("MMM.dd.yyyy", Locale.ITALIAN).parse(s))
              .execute("-d=31.07.1969", "--default=Gennaio.01.2020");
    }
}
```

The first invocation with invalid input `-d=55.55.55` prints the following output:

```
Invalid value for option '--date': cannot convert '55.55.55' to Date (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: year should be after 1900)
Usage: demo [-d=dd.MM.yyyy] [-x=yyyy-MM-dd]
  -d, --date=dd.MM.yyyy      Date in German format `dd.MM.yyyy`
  -x, --default=yyyy-MM-dd   This option uses the default converter
```

The second invocation, where we pass `--default=Gennaio.01.2020` to confirm that the global type converter now handles dates in our custom Italian format, gives the following output:

```
[-d=31.07.1969, --default=Gennaio.01.2020] -> Thu Jul 31 00:00:00 JST 1969; Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 JST 2020
```

Comment: Was this answer useful to you? If it solved the problem, please accept the answer. If now, please clarify what still remains to be done.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment. However, it looks like that this means that we need an individual type converter class for each date format.Other CLI libs offer handler/converter parameters (e.g. args4j) to specify a format pattern. Lacking this feature results in increased migration effort and reduced flexibility.

Comment: @MRalwasser I updated my answer. Picocli does not require a full class: a lambda is often sufficient for a custom date converter. Example: `new CommandLine(new MyApp()).registerConverter(Date.class, s -> new SimpleDateFormat("MMM.dd.yyyy", Locale.ITALIAN).parse(s)).execute("--date=Gennaio.01.2020")`. (See also [picocli-examples](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/blob/master/picocli-examples/src/main/java/picocli/examples/dateformat/DateFormatExample.java).) Would this meet your needs?

Comment: Thank you for your update. However, as lambda expressions are syntax sugar only, it does not help much as we still need to create an individual converter (class) for each possible date format and refer to them in the @Option. I can live with it, however having the ability providing arguments to a converter would really simplify things (and would bring picocli to the same level as args4j regarding this topic).

Comment: I looked at Args4j but could not find a DateConverter. Perhaps you have a different CLI library in mind? Can you point me to a concrete example of how a format pattern should be specified in an option definition?

Comment: You're right, we implemented our own args4j Date Handler (extending `OneArgumentOptionHandler`). However, args4j provides a `metaVar` attribute on its `Option` annotation which is passed to the handler. We use `metaVar` to speficy a date format pattern which our own Data Handler reads and uses for parsing the actual String argument value. Is there something similar in Picocli?

Comment: @MRalwasser Yes, the equivalent of arg4j's `metaVar` in picocli is [`paramLabel`](https://picocli.info/apidocs/picocli/CommandLine.Option.html#paramLabel--). This attribute is available for both options and positional parameters and works similarly (shown in usage help). However, the `ITypeConverter` interface does not give access to the `ArgSpec`... You may want to implement a custom [`IParameterConsumer`](https://picocli.info/#_custom_parameter_processing) instead. This will give you access to the `ArgSpec`, so you can get its `paramLabel`.